# Is it possible to customize the indent style of XCode?

Tags: c++, xcode, formatting, coding-style

For example, I'd like to not indent namespaces in C++ code, but the prefpane doesn't seem to have any place to make a decision of this granularity. Is there some hidden config file or something? Or am I just out of luck?

Answer (score 9):

Apple's XCode documentation contains a [full list of user preferences](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/developertools/Reference/XcodeUserDefaultRef/100-Xcode_User_Defaults/UserDefaultRef.html), many of them that don't have a corresponding UI. I'm not seeing anything that is namespace-specific however, so I think you might be out of luck.

However, I thought I'd pass along the preferences list in case it's useful.

Comment: Dude, the link is broken :(

Answer (score 7):

I've also attempted to do this.

The answer is that whoever did the code formatting in XCode appears to be completely unaware that there are languages other than Objective C, or coding styles other than Apple's.

Here's a list of things that one would want to do that can't be done in XCode.

1. Indent public: or private: just one space.
2. Indent namespaces zero spaces.
3. Alternate indentation for arguments NOT relative to the opening parenthesis.

The last one needs a little discussion.  Sometimes, a function or method name can be quite long, as well as its first argument, so you want also to be able to indent like this:

```
someExcitingClass->AVeryLongMethodNameTraLaLaLaLa(
    someLongExpressionOrVariableNameGoesHere,
    anotherNameHere);
```

Of course, you might want to be extracting subexpressions to make the line shorter, but in real-world code this comes up all the time, and creating subexpressions just to fit everything into a reasonable line length is annoying.

It's a terrible shame and I really have no idea what to do.  I personally write in emacs and only dip into XCode as a build system but :-D that's not for everyone.

Answer (score 6):

As the Xcode indenter uses just the lexer, and not the AST, you can 'fool' the formatting by defining away the curly braces.

I have:

```
#define NAMESPACE_OPEN(_name) namespace _name {
#define NAMESPACE_CLOSE(_name) }

#define dsmsg_namespace_open NAMESPACE_OPEN(dsmsg)
#define dsmsg_namespace_close NAMESPACE_CLOSE(dsmsg)
```

i.e., a generic 'NAMESPACE_OPEN/CLOSE' define, and a define specific to my most-used namespace 'dsmsg'. Then, whenever I want to open the namespace, I use

```
dsmsg_namespace_open

... code ...

dsmsg_namespace_close
```

Ugly hack, but I quite like having a specific, named 'close'

Comment: Just stumbled upon this 3.5 years later, and it's a great hack.

Answer (score 5):

I bypass Xcode's indenting altogether, and have a user script that calls [uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) on the currently displayed document.

```
#!/bin/sh
#echo -n "%%%{PBXSelection}%%%"
uncrustify -q -c ~/.uncrustify/sample.cfg -l oc+
#echo -n "%%%{PBXSelection}%%%"
```

Notes:

- uncrustify must be in your PATH
- you may need to adjust the location of your config file
- if you want to have the new code selected in Xcode, uncomment the two echo statements (this can also be used to make a "Format Selection" script, rather than "Format All"

Script Settings:

- Input:Entire Document
- Directory: Home directory
- Output: Replace Document Contents
- Errors: display in alert

Answer (score 4):

As of Xcode 4.3.1 no custom namespace indent options are available, however I overcame this irritation by navigating to Preferences->Text Editing->Indentation and disabling "Syntax-aware indenting".

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to use Articstic Style (astyle). A tutorial how to integrate astyle into XCode using automator and services can be found here: http://eatmyrandom.blogspot.com/2011/03/xcode-astyle-part-2-for-xcode-4x.html and http://youtu.be/d8bbE6_OHGc